# Find all values in a column and retrieve the addresses in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the .find function in VBA to find instances of a value in a column, however there are calculations which are made based on criteria on the same rows as where the value is found. This is problematic because although the value I am looking for might be the same, the criteria which are used to create the overall score are different. As a result, I would need to loop through all the values which are found in the column and I was wondering how to do that in vba. I know the findnext function but I can never get it to work properly.

```
 counted = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(cl.Range(finletter & "9:" & finletter & "317"), "Value", cl.Range("H9:H317"), wl.Range("A" & y.row).Value)
        'Pol small low complex
        If counted > 0 Then
            MsgBox wl.Range("A" & y.row).Value
        If cl.Range("C" & y.row).Value < 3 And cl.Range("D" & y.row).Value = 1 And cl.Range("E" & y.row).Value = "Interim" Then

        wl.Range(y.Address) = 3.75 * counted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.  Say we are looking for the text "LOVE" in column **A** and process the data on those rows:

```
Option Base 1

Sub LookingForLove()
    Dim s As String, rng As Range, WhichRows() As Long
    Dim rFound As Range

    ReDim WhichRows(1)

    s = "LOVE"
    Set rng = Range("A1:A25")
    Set rFound = rng.Find(What:=s, After:=rng(1))
    WhichRows(1) = rFound.Row

    Do
        Set rFound = rng.FindNext(After:=rFound)
        If rFound.Row = WhichRows(1) Then Exit Do
        ReDim Preserve WhichRows(UBound(WhichRows) + 1)
        WhichRows(UBound(WhichRows)) = rFound.Row
    Loop

    msg = UBound(WhichRows) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    For i = 1 To UBound(WhichRows)
        msg = msg & WhichRows(i) & vbCrLf
    Next i

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

*NOTE:*

- the `Exit Do` prevents looping forever
- your code would continue by looping the elements of `WhichRows()` and processing the items on those rows.
- your code could alternatively create a dynamic array of ranges or cell addresses.

Another alternative approach would be to use *VBA* to establish an **AutoFilter** and process the visible rows.